# Sendgrid account open from Azure now is not listed as Sengrid account

Tags: azure, sendgrid

Sendgrid account open from Azure now is not listed as Sengrid account. 
From Sendgrid site the account is working and fully functional.

Is there a way to add exist account to bottom of Azure account?

If answer is no, is exist way to copy all settings and data from one Sendgrid account to other.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking via the classic portal (`manage.windowsazure.com`) or new portal (`portal.azure.com`)?

Comment: via new portal (portal.azure.com)

Comment: This is really a portal functionality thing - you should still be able to see it in the classic portal.  (the new portal lets you manage SendGrid services within the scope of Resource Manager / resource groups). Not a question for Stackoverflow though - just a portal thing.

Comment: If I don't be able to see it in the classic portal is this mean viewed sendgrid account is don't added over Azure? Thanks for quick response

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot use an existing account, you have to create a new account dedicated for your online service linked with Azure, and from the sendgrid portal you can do whatever you want, but as David Makogon said, it's a portal thing.